# callback vs promise mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm learning mongodb and have stumbled upon an issue. I can't get why a callback function doesn't allow a promise to be executed and I get deletedCount 0.
Let assume I have 2 items in my 'users' collection:
1.

```
User.deleteMany()
    .then(result => console.log(result.deletedCount)) // 2  this works fine.
```

2. In this situation I add 2 items to my 'users' collection again, but get 0 deletedCount:

```
 User.deleteMany({}, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
}).then(result => console.log(result.deletedCount))  // 0
```

3. when I add 'result' as a second argument into the callback it works fine, but without a promise:

```
User.deleteMany({}, function(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(`Deleted ${result.deletedCount} items.`);  // 2
})
```

So why do I get in #2 deletedCount == 0 ?

Comment: The two invocation styles are mutually exclusive. You can use `catch` with promise style to handle errors.

Comment: In #2 the command is executed twice, once for the callback and again for the `.then`, the second run will find nothing to delete.

Comment: Thanks @Joe, which way is more preferable?

Comment: Unless you are working with a team that has state coding guidelines, that is a matter of personal preference.